# jquery post in mobile browser doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to make a post request with jQuery in a web application with the following code :

```
alert('1');
$.post(server_hostname, 
       { method: 'getTimestamp', type: 'text', partnerKey: partnerKey },
       function(results, textStatus) {
           alert(results)
           alert('2');
       },
       'text');
```

That's working very well in chrome and firefox on my computer but not in safari for iOS nor in the Android browser. I guess $.post() doesn't success in a mobile browser but why?
On the other hand, how can I see the javascript errors output with my iPhone/Android ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you datatype `'text'` should be `xml, json, script, or html`

for more information see [jQuery's post documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: OK but why does it work in Chrome and Firefox?
Furthermore, if I absolutely want to use the text format, can I use $.ajax to do that?

Comment: true that it's odd that it works in chrome/firefox. I guess if you want to handle the response as text, you should use html as datatype. However I was wondering if this was solution?

Comment: Safari is more strict with syntax. If you want text, use either json or html.

Comment: Actually the problem was in my server hostname, sorry about that. The code above works pretty well in safari for iOS, Opera Mobile and the android browser. Probably because $.post() is just a higher level function using $.ajax which supports 'text' as dataType.