# jquery post request doesn't work in mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, aws-api-gateway

I am posting form data to an API that doesn't require a header type or any additional options.

```
        var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
        var number = '+1' + document.getElementById('tel').value;
        var user = JSON.stringify({
          name: name,
          phone_number: number
        });
        $.post("https://api.com/signup", user, function (data) {
          alert(data);
        });
```

This works fine in desktop browsers, however it doesn't seem to work in any mobile browsers. I have seen the [other question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062740/jquery-post-in-mobile-browser-doesnt-work)  with a similar title but I tried setting the type and it makes no difference. I have tried using various methods , such as replacing the click event with "touch" event listeners to no avail. I am starting to think this is directly related to the API, I am sending JSON data but I don't know if on a mobile device it is somehow being changed to x-www-form-urlencoded data, in which case the API doesn't accept that format. The API is my own setup using AWS API Gateway, and it only works with JSON data, is perhaps changing this to accept query strings a viable option?

Comment: What do you mean API Gateway only accept JSON data? It is supporting binary data and String data in the payload, and supporting data from the path, header, query string as well. Can you go through how your API setup on API Gateway side?

Comment: What specifically do you need to know? THe API is setup to trigger a Lambda function using the Type: LAMBDA_PROXY, it has open access (no auth required) and it expects JSON input, and apparently doesn't take query strings.

Comment: Lambda is expecting JSON as an input, but API Gateway will map all the parameters you pass to API Gateway to the payload, like query string, path parameter, headers.